# Calculate 2D Intercept point of Two Infinite Lines

Tags: python, math, 2d

Using the formula y=mx+b I have written the below code to solve the point of intersection for two infinite lines without the use of any dependencies such as numpy. I am specifically looking to achieve a dependency free solution.

Unfortunately, It consistently returns the wrong result when solving for the Y intercept of each line, and consequently, everything after it will be wrong as a result. After hammering away at this for days its about time to put it up here for someone else to look at it.

The lines are defined by an origin point and a radian of what direction they are slanted in. Please note that I have deliberately removed checks for lines parallel with the Y axis (Such lines don't have a slope) and other edge cases for better readability in this example.

The code is written with long form variables for further clarity. I have looked at many questions regarding similar problems and other websites and answers are almost always codified in mathematical notation, assume you know what the variables represent, or it is assumed that the Op knows how to solve for unknown variables / balance equations. I know very little of such things, I have essentially had to teach myself algebra all over again to try and solve this. My goal here is to provide maximum clarity so others with this problem can understand how to take the formula and solve it as Python code.

```
import math

origin_a = [0.9292893218813453, 0.07071]
origin_b = [3.121320343559643, 2.121320343559643]

radian_a = math.pi/4
radian_b = 2.748893571891069

X = 0
Y = 1
Z = 2


"""Returns Vector2 around a circle"""
def get_position_from_radian(radian, radius):
    rotated_pos = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    rotated_pos[X] = math.cos(math.pi-radian) * radius
    rotated_pos[Y] = math.sin(math.pi-radian) * radius
    return(rotated_pos)


"""Returns Vector2"""
def get_slope_from_radian(radian):
    slope = (get_position_from_radian(radian, 1)) #Get a position along line to calculate slope from
    #We want slope to be scalar for simplicity, so we will divide Y by X and assume X=1
    slope = slope[Y] / slope[X]
    return(slope)


"""Returns Vector2 where two 2D rays intersect using y=mx+b (slope intercept)"""
def get_position_from_line_intersect_2d(origin_a, radian_a, origin_b, radian_b):
    #Slope is the 'm' in y=mx+b
    slope_a = get_slope_from_radian(radian_a)
    slope_b = get_slope_from_radian(radian_b)

    #Trig to find the slope of our lines. We assume length x=1 
    angle_a = math.pi - math.pi/2 - radian_a
    angle_b = math.pi - math.pi/2 - radian_b
    #We must determine if angle is + or - X
    if radian_a > math.pi:
        slope_a *= -1 
    if radian_b > math.pi:  
        slope_b *= -1
    print("SLOPE", slope_a, slope_b)

    #These represent the Y intercept
    intercept_y_a = origin_a[Y] + -(slope_a * origin_a[X])
    intercept_y_b = origin_b[Y] + -(slope_b * origin_b[X])
    print("Y INTERCEPT", intercept_y_a, intercept_y_b)

    #These represent the X intercept
    intercept_x_a = slope_a * intercept_y_a
    intercept_x_b = slope_b * intercept_y_b
    print("X INTERCEPT", intercept_x_a, intercept_x_b)

    #This is the position at which our two lines intersect
    intercept = [0.0, 0.0]
    intercept[X] = ((intercept_y_a*-1) + intercept_y_b) / (slope_a (slope_b*-1))
    intercept[Y] = ((intercept_x_a*-1) + intercept_x_b) / (slope_a (slope_b*-1))

    return(intercept)

print(get_position_from_line_intersect_2d(origin_a, radian_a, origin_b, radian_b))
```

Comment: Please explain `intercept[X] = ((intercept_y_a*-1) + intercept_y_b) / (slope_a (slope_b*-1))`.
`

Comment: Are you simply looking at the intersection between two lines? That is, at the intersection of two equations of the form y=a1*x+b1 and y=a2*x+b2? In such case you would just need to assume they are equal and isolate x (then find y trivially).

Comment: From what I can tell. in algebra, if you want to find a point common to two equations you need to place the equations on opposite sides of the = sign. In the case of y=mx+b that looks like mx+b=mx+b. To solve it you would subtract a variable from one side while adding it to the other. You cant define equations that way in Python unless importing some algebra solving module. So to balance it, when we need to move both of the b variables to one side, we can say that instead of b=b, we do =b+(b*-1) where *-1 reverses the +/- that was moved from the other side.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the XY intercept between the two lines. I am learning how to do algebra from the ground up to solve this so please excuse my naivety on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would implement it starting from your code

```
import math

origin_a = [0.9292893218813453, 0.07071]
origin_b = [3.121320343559643, 2.121320343559643]

radian_a = math.pi/4
radian_b = 2.748893571891069

X = 0
Y = 1
Z = 2

"""Returns Vector2 where two 2D rays intersect using y=mx+b (slope intercept)"""
def get_position_from_line_intersect_2d(origin_a, radian_a, origin_b, radian_b):
    #Slope is the 'm' in y=mx+b
    m1 = math.tan( radian_a) # get_slope_from_radian(radian_a)
    m2 = math.tan( radian_b) # get_slope_from_radian(radian_b)

    print("SLOPE", m1, m2)

    #These represent the Y intercept
    b1 = origin_a[Y] - (m1 * origin_a[X])
    b2 = origin_b[Y] - (m2 * origin_b[X])
    print("Y INTERCEPT", b1, b2)

    #This is the position at which our two lines intersect
    iX = (b2 - b1) / ( m1 - m2)
    iY = m1 * iX + b1

    return( iX, iY)

a,b = get_position_from_line_intersect_2d(origin_a, radian_a, origin_b, radian_b)
```

There are a couple thing that where not clear in your implementation:

- Why do you use `math.pi-radian` instead of just `radian`. If this is your intended behavior than you can just take -m1 and -m2 with respect to how i defined them from `tan(pi - a) = -tan(a)`
- There is no need to check for angles greater than pi. The slope will always be defined as the tangent of the angle
- There is no need to calculate the intercept with x=0 you just solve for `y1= b1*x + m1,  y2= b2*x + m2`, then `y1=y2  --> x_intercept=(b2-b1)/(m1-m2)` and finally `y_intercept = m1 *x_i +b1 = m2 *x_i + b2`

[image]

Case with the `pi - rad` definition:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an '*how to implement this*' kind of answer please look at my first answer.
Here I'll try to explain why your implementation is not working from a math point of view

First check that
**math.pi-radian**  actually is your intended behavior in (this is equivalent to defining all your angle as negative)

```
def get_position_from_radian(radian, radius):
    rotated_pos = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    rotated_pos[X] = math.cos(math.pi-radian) * radius
    rotated_pos[Y] = math.sin(math.pi-radian) * radius
    return(rotated_pos)
```

Also you really should remove this.

```
if radian_a > math.pi:
    slope_a *= -1 
if radian_b > math.pi:  
    slope_b *= -1
```

The correct way to get the slope is `m = tan(angle) = sin(angle)/cos(angle)`.
For the sake of simplicity lets put `b=0`, now lets imagine you have one angle as pi/4. You will get `m = sqrt(2)/2 > 0` which is good since `0 < angle < pi or pi < angle < 3/2 * pi` will define a line in the 1st and 3rd section of your plot.
Now lets take an angle of `pi + pi/4`. This will give you the exact same line as before and the tangent will still give you `m = sqrt(2)/2 > 0` as both the cos and sin are negative in the 3rd section. If you invert the sign because `angle>pi` you actually get the wrong result.

Now what you are doing is solving this system of equations:

```
y = m1 * x + b1
y = m2 * x + b2
```

which leads to `x_itercept = (b2-b1) / (m1-m2)`.
Up to now your formula seems correct (beside the missing + in the implementation) `intercept[X] = ((intercept_y_a*-1) + intercept_y_b) / (slope_a (slope_b*-1))`.

The problem start when you try to switch the axis and use the exact same formula for the y intercept.
In order to do this lets invert the equation of the line `y(x) --> x(y)` (which we can do since this is a monotonic function with one *distinct* value of y for every x.

```
x = (y - b1) / m1
x = (y - b2) / m2
```

Lets change some names to bring this in the most common form of x = slope * y + b

```
m' = 1/m
b' = -b/m
x = m1' * y + b1'
x = m2' * y + b2'
```

Now we can solve this system exactly as the first one and we obtain

```
y_intercept = (b2' - b1') / (m1' - m2')
```

The structure of the formula is the same as the one you use, but as you can see the variable in it are different!!!!!!!
You get the b1' and b2' right as you calculate the intercept of the line with the x-axis, but you still use m1 and m2 as the slope instead of 1/m1 and 1/m2